# how to prevent user response during delay before the AI response

Tags: xcode, swift

I am having trouble with being able to keep activating buttons before my AI response in a Tic Tac Toe game. As you can see I added a delay response, but I am still able to do another turn even before my AI responds. Anyone knows how to disable the first player turn until the AI has made its turn?

```
@IBOutlet var userMessage: UILabel!

struct Sender{
    var tag = 1
    }

var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
var done = false
var aiDeciding = false
var sender: Sender = Sender()


@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    userMessage.hidden = true
    if plays[sender.tag] == nil && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImageForSpot(sender.tag, player: 1)

    }
    checkForWin()
    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {

        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)

    }
    delay(0.4) {
        self.aiTurn()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set [enabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled) on any buttons to `false` or set [userInteractionEnabeled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled) on the entire view to `false` during AI "playback" to prevent the user from interacting with your interface.

Comment: How would you write that then?

Comment: @Pjc1992 `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false` when starting the animation and `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true` when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Take your entire `UIButtonClicked` method and wrap it in an if clause to see if the AI is deciding:

```
@IBAction func UIButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    if (!aiDeciding) {
        //all of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Garrett. I tried it as you explained it, but it did not work for some reason... Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting aiDeciding to true at some point?